# Javascript Object Required

Tags: c#, javascript

In my project I am checking the email Id of the user during registration to it is valid or not I am using the Javascript.I am getting the value of the Textbox in the function during button click and verifying it but during click of the button it shows **Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required** error Can any one point out what would be wrong in my code,

My javascript Function is,

```
   function mailcheck() {

    var txt = document.getElementById("emailid").value;
    if (txt != "") {
        var at = "@"
        var dot = "."
        var lat = str.indexOf(at)
        var lstr = str.length
        var ldot = str.indexOf(dot)
        if (txt.indexOf(at) == -1) {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            obj.focus()
            return false
        }

        if (txt.indexOf(at) == -1 || txt.indexOf(at) == 0 || txt.indexOf(at) == ltxt) {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            obj.focus()
            return false
        }

        if (txt.indexOf(dot) == -1 || txt.indexOf(dot) == 0 || txt.indexOf(dot) == lstr) {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            obj.focus()
            return false
        }

        if (str.indexOf(at, (lat + 1)) != -1) {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            obj.focus()
            return false
        }

        if (txt.substring(lat - 1, lat) == dot || txt.substring(lat + 1, lat + 2) == dot) {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            obj.focus()
            return false
        }

        if (txt.indexOf(dot, (lat + 2)) == -1) {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            obj.focus()
            return false
        }

        if (txt.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            obj.focus()
            return false

        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: do you have a line / line number of the error?

Comment: Can you post the ASPX/HTML markup

Comment: @GalV it dosen't give any line number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your control is `"runat=server"` if so, the rendered html control name should be something like: #ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_emailid.

Try changing this:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("emailid").value;
```

to this:

```
var txt = document.getElementById('<%=emailid.ClientID %>').value;
```

The ClientID will give you the full name in case the control is inside a content panel.

On the other side you are accessiong the property `obj.focus()`and I can't see **obj** declared inside the scope.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I was focusing Textbox if it is invalid

Comment: Hi I had tried as you said like `Var txt=document.getelementId("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderMain_emailid").value` and it worked perfectly, thanks for pointing out the error

Comment: You are welcome @Rajesh. Always have in mind if control is runat=server and It is inside a content holder panel it will render with different name ;)

Answer (score 2):

it seems like you're referring `obj` object (as in `obj.focus()`) but there's no declaration of it. this may cause the error.

also, if the text element has `runat="server"` - you must refer to it with `document.getElementById('<%= emailid.ClientID %>')`

Comment: Sorry my mistake I was focusing Textbox if it is invalid

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using C#, you should be using clientID generated by .NET

`document.getElementById('<%= emailid.ClientID %>')`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a server side control to input the email address? Because if you are the ID will change when the page renders, so you have to use

```
document.getElementById('<%= emailid.ClientID%>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up your variable names. Where are str and ltxt defined?

Try this:

```
function mailcheck() {

    var txt = document.getElementById("emailid").value;
    if (txt != "") {
        var at = "@"
        var dot = "."
        var lat = txt.indexOf(at)
        var ltxt = txt.length
        var ldot = txt.indexOf(dot)
        console.log('yeah');
        if (txt.indexOf(at) == -1) {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            obj.focus()
            return false
        }
        if (txt.indexOf(at) == -1 || txt.indexOf(at) == 0 || txt.indexOf(at) == ltxt) {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            obj.focus()
            return false
        }

        if (txt.indexOf(dot) == -1 || txt.indexOf(dot) == 0 || txt.indexOf(dot) == ltxt) {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            obj.focus()
            return false
        }

        if (txt.indexOf(at, (lat + 1)) != -1) {
            alert("Invalid E-mail ID")
            obj.focus()
            return false
        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```